# Function with 3 variables in a 4D space

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, 3d

Is the representation of a function with 3 variables in a 4D space a surface or a volume?

In 2D a function is a (eventually) curved line, in 3D is a (eventually) curved surface, so I think in 4D it will be a volume that eventually curves in the 4th dimension, is it right?

Comment: the composite word "hypersurface" would be